# Password Settings of AIX

Tags: password, aix, etc

```
esaadmin:
    password = *

dbahx:
    password = *************

sysgina:
    password = *************

fsecbp:
    password = C6qoi9yK.H0So
```

Hi All,
I am trying to understand what does

```
password = *************
```

in the second stanza mean? For the first stanza for esaadmin, I understand that

```
password = *
```

means that password is not set for that specific user and that user cannot login until root account set a password for it.

In the last stanza,

```
password = C86oi9yK.919
```

this is the encrypted passwords using AIX default crypt hash.

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM Knowledge Center for that /etc/security/passwd](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/filesreference/passwd_security.html) says that the `passwd` attribute:

> Specifies the encrypted password.

I would interpret those entries to be attempts by an administrator to prevent logins for those accounts. As you saw, the values for that field are: empty ("no password"), a single `*` ("cannot log in"), or the encrypted password. With the default [pwd_algorithm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/filesreference/login.cfg.html#login.cfg) of `crypt`, it would be impossible to have an encrypted password that matches `*************`.